# Why does Tkinter kill ability to highlight text?

Tags: copy, tkinter, highlight, paste

I'm running ubuntu11.04, and python3 with tkinter. I've yet to check on a windows config, but whenever I have a mainloop() running and a root window open with tkinter, I can't highlight text in text edit/ gui manager stuff. It doesn't leave me helpless, but copy/paste is a fairly integral part of my efficiency when navigating and coding. Has anyone else experienced this? Anyone know a fix?

-Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What do you mean by "text edit/ gui manager stuff"? Are you saying that when you create an empty tkinter widnow that it clears the selection in non-tk windows? Can you give us the absolutely smallest example of a tkinter application that causes this behavior?

Comment: Having just a basic `root = Tk()`, will disable the ability for me to highlight text (as in click, and drag over text to highlight for copying/editing/etc) in a text editor. I can't do any of this with an instance of Tk() open. I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 running python3 and I, for example, will not be able to highlight inside Ubuntu's basic Text Editor.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in whatever window manager you are using and/or in that specific version of ubuntu. This is a problem that hasn't been reported on any other platform, or on any other versions of linux.